# Matroid type class (error) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, greedy

A finite matroid M is a pair (E, I), where E is a finite set (called the ground set) and I is a family of subsets of E (called independent sets).

A weighted matroid is a matroid W equipped with a weight function w: E -> Int (positive integers).

We can define a (weighted) matroid typeclass as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Matroid matroid a where
  weight :: matroid -> a -> Int 
  groundSet :: matroid -> [a]
  indepSet :: [a] -> Bool
```

We can then define various algorithms for matroids.  For example choosing a basis set F with minimal weight.  When applied to graphs, this is Kruskal's algorithm for finding a minimal weight spanning tree.

An instance of a (weighted) matroid is a (weighted) graph G = (E, w) where E is a collection of edges, w is a weight function.  To define a matroid from a graph, we take the ground set to be the collection of edges E and a subset F of E is independent if and only if it is acyclic.

```
instance Matroid WGraph Edge where
  weight = wT 
  groundSet = gSet
  indepSet = iSet

type Vertex = Int
type Edge = (Vertex, Vertex)
type Graph = [Edge]
type WtFun = Edge -> Int
type WGraph = (Graph, WtFun)

gSet :: WGraph -> [Edge]
gSet (es,wt) = es 

wT :: WGraph -> (WtFun)
wT (es,wt) = wt
-- stub
iSet :: [Edge] -> Bool
iSet edges = True
```

However given a weighted graph, the following code has a type error

```
weightedG = (es, wt)::WGraph
es = [(4,5),(6,7),(5,7)]::[Edge]
wt :: (Edge -> Int)
wt (4,5) = 15
wt (6,7) = 11
wt (5,7) = 9
gs = groundSet weightedG

No instance for (Matroid WGraph a0)
  arising from a use of `groundSet'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

How can we specify that a0 should be an Edge type?

Code for copy/paste:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Matroid matroid a where
  weight :: matroid -> a -> Int 
  groundSet :: matroid -> [a]
  indepSet :: [a] -> Bool

instance Matroid WGraph Edge where
  weight = wT 
  groundSet = gSet
  indepSet = iSet

type Vertex = Int
type Edge = (Vertex, Vertex)
type Graph = [Edge]
type WtFun = Edge -> Int
type WGraph = (Graph, WtFun)

gSet :: WGraph -> [Edge]
gSet (es,wt) = es 

wT :: WGraph -> (WtFun)
wT (es,wt) = wt

-- fix for real implementation
iSet :: [Edge] -> Bool
iSet edges = True

weightedG = (es, wt)::WGraph
es = [(4,5),(6,7),(5,7)]::[Edge]
wt :: (Edge -> Int)
wt (4,5) = 15
wt (6,7) = 11
wt (5,7) = 9
gs = groundSet weightedG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is indicating that GHC doesn't know which `Matroid` instance you want for `weightedG`.

It knows that you want a `Matroid WGraph a` for some type `a`, and you have
defined an instance `Matroid Graph Edge`, but since type classes are open there is no way for GHC conclude that `a` must be `Edge`. Later or in another module you (or someone else) could define a `Matroid WGraph String` instance - for instance.

One way around this is to introduce a functional dependency between the matroid type and the element type like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Matroid matroid a | matroid -> a where
   ...
```

This tells GHC that the `matroid` type determines the edge type `a`. With this change I got your code to compile.